# Save multiple selected checkboxes in the database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

i hope someone can help me. i have 4 checkboxes i want to save it in one string in my database,for example you only choose 2 or 3 checkboxes options.. the selected values only will save in one field of my database..

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Plan Description:</label></td>
</table>
<?php 
    $des_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addons;") or die ("Note: ". mysql_error());
?>

<?php
    while($desc = mysql_fetch_array($des_query))
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='addons[]' value=".$desc['id'].">". $desc['name']."</input><br/>";
    }
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3
these array for example i want them to save in one field on my database. please help me how to do that.

Comment: Use a for loop and concatanate the posted checkbox values into one string and save it

Comment: @Deepu just like this one? 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO plan_addons (plan_id, addon_id)
 VALUES ('$_POST[plan_id]', '$_POST[addons]' )")
 
  $len = count($_POST['addons']);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){

echo [$_POST] [$i];

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$insStr = ''; 
foreach($_POST['addons'] as $val){ $insStr .=$val.","; }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO promos (promo) VALUES ( '$insStr' )");
```

Comment: you can also use `implode`

Comment: @Deepu 
I've got an error. please check my code if this is correct.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO promos (promo)
 VALUES ( '$_POST[addons]' )");
 
  $insStr = '';
foreach($_POST['addons'] as $val){
   $insStr .=$val.",";
}

Comment: here is the error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Globes\plan.php on line 17

Comment: line 17: VALUES ( '$_POST[addons]' )");

Comment: I have updated the answer.Check it.You have misplaced the single quotes

Comment: @Deepu it works! :) but there's a little problem only the first word were saved. here are my checkboxes []Unlimited Call []Unlimited Text []Unlimited Data []300 Text,    when i checked them here is the result:  [addons] => Array ( [0] => Unlimited [1] => Unlimited [2] => Unlimited [3] => 300 )  only the first word were fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize() method 
example

```
    $arr = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3);
    $str = serialize($arr);
```

After retrieving from database use unserialize() method

Comment: Thank you for the help.. well appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of PHP built-in function named `implode`

**Example**

```
$checkboxValue implode(',',$_POST['addons']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. well appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if(!empty($_POST['addons'])) { $addons_string="";foreach($_POST['addons'] as $addon){$addons_string.=$addon.","; } }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. well appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

test.php

```
<form name="test" action="test1.php" method="get">
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<9;$i++){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name=a[] value=$i>$i<br>";
    }
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and test1.php

```
<?php
foreach($_GET['a'] as $check) {
    echo $check;
    //SAVE VALUES TO DATABASE
}
?>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you for the help.. well appreciated.. :)